# Apple pay billing address tax calculation

Tags: ios, swift, stripe-payments, applepay

I'm trying to implement Apple pay with Stripe with the following flow

- select product
- tap apple pay (the summary of the item/s is shown without the taxes)
- upon selecting/updating the billing addres, taxes are calculated and `paymentSummaryItems` updated to display the final amount
- perform the payment

but I cannot find a way to extract the billing info prior to payment authorisation to calculate and apply the taxes. For shipping address there is a delegate callback

```
func applePayContext(_ context: STPApplePayContext, didSelectShippingContact contact: PKContact, handler: @escaping (PKPaymentRequestShippingContactUpdate) -> Void) {}
```

which is called every time the shipping address is updated, but it's not the same for the billing one.

Is this even the correct flow to follow or the taxes should be calculated prior displaying the `PKPaymentAuthorizationController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that there is a callback for the billing address but it is in the `PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate`

```
    // update the summary items in response to the card type changing (for example, applying credit card surcharges)
    //
    // The delegate will receive no further callbacks except paymentAuthorizationControllerDidFinish:
    // until it has invoked the completion block.
    
    @available(iOS 11.0, *)
    optional func paymentAuthorizationController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController, didSelectPaymentMethod paymentMethod: PKPaymentMethod, handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentRequestPaymentMethodUpdate) -> Void)
```

the issue is that Stripe's `STPApplePayContext` does not implement it and therefor not passing it to it's own delegate `STPApplePayContextDelegate` as it does with the shipping address.

The quick solution is to implement it yourself:

```
struct AssociatedKeys {
    static var postalCodeCompletion: String = "postalCodeCompletionKey"
}

extension STPApplePayContext {
    // 1
    var didUpdatePostalCodeCompletion: ((CNPostalAddress, (PKPaymentRequestPaymentMethodUpdate) -> Void) -> ())? {
        get {
            guard let value = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.postalCodeCompletion) as? (CNPostalAddress, (PKPaymentRequestPaymentMethodUpdate) -> Void) -> () else {
                return nil
            }
            return value
        }
        set(newValue) {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.postalCodeCompletion, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
        }
    }
    
    @objc
    public func paymentAuthorizationController(_ controller: PKPaymentAuthorizationController,
                                               didSelectPaymentMethod paymentMethod: PKPaymentMethod,
                                               handler completion: @escaping (PKPaymentRequestPaymentMethodUpdate) -> Void) {
        // 2
        guard let address = paymentMethod.billingAddress?.postalAddresses.first?.value else {
            let error = PKPaymentError(.billingContactInvalidError)
            let paymenMethodUpdate = PKPaymentRequestPaymentMethodUpdate(errors: [error], paymentSummaryItems: [])
            completion(paymenMethodUpdate)
            
            return
        }
        
        didUpdatePostalCodeCompletion?(address, completion)
    }
}
```

1. Since we are using extension the associated object is the way to store values
2. I need only the address here (yes, it's not full) so I only pass it to the stored completion + the completion from the delegate

**note**: You have to call the completion from the delegate as soon as you are ready with the calculations

How to use it:

```
        let merchantIdentifier = "your merch ID"
        let paymentRequest = StripeAPI.paymentRequest(withMerchantIdentifier: merchantIdentifier, country: "US", currency: "USD")

        // 1
        paymentRequest.paymentSummaryItems = []

        // Initialize an STPApplePayContext instance
        if let applePayContext = STPApplePayContext(paymentRequest: paymentRequest, delegate: self) {
            // Present Apple Pay payment sheet
            
            applePayContext.didUpdatePostalCodeCompletion = { address, completion in
                
                // 2
                let newSummaryItems = [
                    PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "my new fancy hat", amount: 1),
                    PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Tax", amount: 1),
                    PKPaymentSummaryItem(label: "Total", amount: 2)
                ]
                
                let pkpaymentrequest = PKPaymentRequestPaymentMethodUpdate(errors: nil, paymentSummaryItems: newSummaryItems)
                // 3
                completion(pkpaymentrequest)
            }
            applePayContext.presentApplePay(completion: nil)

        } else {
            print("There is a problem with your Apple Pay configuration")
        }
    }
```

1. Generate the initial summary items
2. Do whatever calculations you need to get the tax or whatever extra charges based on the address
3. You have to call the completion that is passed from the `PKPaymentAuthorizationControllerDelegate` (haven't tested it but based on `didAuthorizePayment` you have ~30 sec to do it)

Comment: Hi, @wootage thanks for your answer. But applePayContext.didUpdatePostalCodeCompletion not executing.

Comment: Ohh, it is only getting in "paymentSummeryitem", not in requiredShippingContactFields. is it possible to add this on requiredShippingContactFields?

Comment: The `didSelectShippingContact` is implemented in the stripe framework and has it's own delegate `STPApplePayContextDelegate.applePayContext(_:didSelectShippingContact:handler:))`. You can implement it in your class and handle the shipping part

Answer (score 0):

When using Apple Pay without a shipping address you should collect the information required to calculate tax prior to displaying the Apple Pay sheet and include the tax information when asking your customer to pay (meaning the tax should be visible as a distinct line item on the Apple Pay sheet).

If you were collecting a shipping address you would calculate taxes based on the shipping address using [`STPApplePayContextDelegate`](https://stripe.dev/stripe-ios/docs/Protocols/STPApplePayContextDelegate.html) to update the tax displayed on the Apple Pay sheet as the customer selects/changes their shipping address.

Apple Pay does not make the billing address available to you before the customer confirms the payment for privacy reasons, and only parts of the shipping address are made available before the payment is confirmed:

> To maintain privacy, the shipping information is anonymized. For example, in the United States it only includes the city, state, and zip code. This provides enough information to calculate shipping costs, without revealing sensitive information until the user actually approves the purchase.